# Kallah and the Power to give Brachas

Tags: sources-mekorot

In a shiur given by Rabbi Frand, he [tells over a story](http://youtu.be/rmgghP7Dnxk?t=37m49s)
where a Kallah came into a hospital on the day of her wedding to give Brachas to the children for a Kallah, on the day of her wedding, has the power to give Brachas. What is the source for this?

Comment: Doesn't everyone always have the power to give Brachos?

Comment: @msh210 IMO the linked question doesn't exactly answer my question unless you can explain otherwise

Comment: But it seems to be the same question, whether answered adequately or not.